# How to return the salesperson who made most revenue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to write a function that determines which sales person had the most revenue and how much, but I get #N/A, any idea why/solve?

Formula

```
=SUMIF(B2:B12,F15,INDEX(D2:D12,0,MATCH(F16,D2:D12,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: To start `MATCH(F16,D2:D12,0)` returns `N/A` because `F16` is empty

Comment: F15 also is empty ...

Comment: It's important to know if the revenue needs to be multiplied still with quantity **and** if you still need to add the reveneu for each salesperson since they occur more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FILTER`- formula

`=FILTER(B2:D12,D2:D12=MAX(D2:D12))`

It returns those rows of the range that have the highest revenue - if there are two salesperson with the same max revenue both will be returned

This following formula first **summarizes the revenues per unique salesperson** and then returns the max value:

```
= LET(salespersonUnique,UNIQUE(B2:B6),
sumPerSalesperson,BYROW(salespersonUnique,
                        LAMBDA(s,SUMIF(B2:B6,s,D2:D6))),
INDEX(SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},salespersonUnique, sumPerSalesperson),2,-1),1))
```

Comment: Maybe it's what OP needs but I doubt it. Note that most salespersons have multiple sales. I suppose OP would need to add these together first.

Comment: @JvdV I think you are right - I will add another option. But still it is not clear why OP referred to F15/F16 in his/her formula